# Android Dynamic GridView updates within seconds

Tags: android, gridview, dynamic, dynamicgridview

I want to create a dashboard wherein I want to populate some data in a GridView in android. For example,

Activity - GridView in which there are two columns.
Each grid is Header Text and Result Text.
Now I want to update only Result Text with time as I am fetching it from database and updating the values in real time.
Keeping my Header and whole view intact.

Can anyone suggest any quick way to do so...??

Answer (score 0):

You only need to update the underlying data of the adapter and call notifyDataSetChanged() so the adapter knows the data was changed.